# Android unable to retrieve nearby places using google api

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to get the nearby places of the location I send by using the google map's api. Below is the url(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY).I created a POJO class using DTO Generator plugin.But in the response method of the retrofit the status variable in the POJO class gives me 'REQUEST_DENIED'.(Main Activity.java)

Log.e("Res",response.body().getStatus());

Am I using retrofit the right way?

RetrofitClient.java:

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    public static Retrofit retrofit=null;
     static final String baseurl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/";
    public static Retrofit getClient()
    {
        if (retrofit==null)
        {
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseurl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

NearbyApi.java:

```
public interface NearbyApi {
    @GET("json?")
    Call<NearbyPlaces> getDetails(@Query("location") String loc,
                                  @Query("radius") String radius,
                                  @Query("type") String type,
                                  @Query("keyword") String keyword,@Query("key") String key);

}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
String loc="-33.8670522,151.1957362";
    String radius="1500";
    String type="restaurant";
    String keyword="cruise";
    String key="****";
    NearbyApi nearbyApi=RetrofitClient.getClient().create(NearbyApi.class);
                        Call<NearbyPlaces> call=nearbyApi.getDetails(loc,radius,type,keyword,key);
                        call.enqueue(new Callback<NearbyPlaces>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<NearbyPlaces> call, Response<NearbyPlaces> response) {

    //                                Log.e("Res",response.body().getStatus());
                                Log.e("Res",response.body().getStatus());
                                }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<NearbyPlaces> call, Throwable t) {
                                Log.e("Response","Failure");
                            }
                        });
```

(NearbyPlaces.java)POJO class:

```
public class NearbyPlaces {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("results")
    private List<Results> results;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("html_attributions")
    private List<String> html_attributions;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Results> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Results> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public List<String> getHtml_attributions() {
        return html_attributions;
    }

    public void setHtml_attributions(List<String> html_attributions) {
        this.html_attributions = html_attributions;
    }

    public static class Results {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("vicinity")
        private String vicinity;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("types")
        private List<String> types;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("scope")
        private String scope;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("reference")
        private String reference;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("rating")
        private int rating;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("plus_code")
        private Plus_code plus_code;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("place_id")
        private String place_id;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("photos")
        private List<Photos> photos;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("opening_hours")
        private Opening_hours opening_hours;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("name")
        private String name;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("id")
        private String id;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("icon")
        private String icon;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("geometry")
        private Geometry geometry;

        public String getVicinity() {
            return vicinity;
        }

        public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
            this.vicinity = vicinity;
        }

        public List<String> getTypes() {
            return types;
        }

        public void setTypes(List<String> types) {
            this.types = types;
        }

        public String getScope() {
            return scope;
        }

        public void setScope(String scope) {
            this.scope = scope;
        }

        public String getReference() {
            return reference;
        }

        public void setReference(String reference) {
            this.reference = reference;
        }

        public int getRating() {
            return rating;
        }

        public void setRating(int rating) {
            this.rating = rating;
        }

        public Plus_code getPlus_code() {
            return plus_code;
        }

        public void setPlus_code(Plus_code plus_code) {
            this.plus_code = plus_code;
        }

        public String getPlace_id() {
            return place_id;
        }

        public void setPlace_id(String place_id) {
            this.place_id = place_id;
        }

        public List<Photos> getPhotos() {
            return photos;
        }

        public void setPhotos(List<Photos> photos) {
            this.photos = photos;
        }

        public Opening_hours getOpening_hours() {
            return opening_hours;
        }

        public void setOpening_hours(Opening_hours opening_hours) {
            this.opening_hours = opening_hours;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getIcon() {
            return icon;
        }

        public void setIcon(String icon) {
            this.icon = icon;
        }

        public Geometry getGeometry() {
            return geometry;
        }

        public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
            this.geometry = geometry;
        }
    }

    public static class Plus_code {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("global_code")
        private String global_code;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("compound_code")
        private String compound_code;

        public String getGlobal_code() {
            return global_code;
        }

        public void setGlobal_code(String global_code) {
            this.global_code = global_code;
        }

        public String getCompound_code() {
            return compound_code;
        }

        public void setCompound_code(String compound_code) {
            this.compound_code = compound_code;
        }
    }

    public static class Photos {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("width")
        private int width;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("photo_reference")
        private String photo_reference;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("html_attributions")
        private List<String> html_attributions;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("height")
        private int height;

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
        }

        public String getPhoto_reference() {
            return photo_reference;
        }

        public void setPhoto_reference(String photo_reference) {
            this.photo_reference = photo_reference;
        }

        public List<String> getHtml_attributions() {
            return html_attributions;
        }

        public void setHtml_attributions(List<String> html_attributions) {
            this.html_attributions = html_attributions;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }
    }

    public static class Opening_hours {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("open_now")
        private boolean open_now;

        public boolean getOpen_now() {
            return open_now;
        }

        public void setOpen_now(boolean open_now) {
            this.open_now = open_now;
        }
    }

    public static class Geometry {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("viewport")
        private Viewport viewport;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("location")
        private Location location;

        public Viewport getViewport() {
            return viewport;
        }

        public void setViewport(Viewport viewport) {
            this.viewport = viewport;
        }

        public Location getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public void setLocation(Location location) {
            this.location = location;
        }
    }

    public static class Viewport {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("southwest")
        private Southwest southwest;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("northeast")
        private Northeast northeast;

        public Southwest getSouthwest() {
            return southwest;
        }

        public void setSouthwest(Southwest southwest) {
            this.southwest = southwest;
        }

        public Northeast getNortheast() {
            return northeast;
        }

        public void setNortheast(Northeast northeast) {
            this.northeast = northeast;
        }
    }

    public static class Southwest {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("lng")
        private double lng;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("lat")
        private double lat;

        public double getLng() {
            return lng;
        }

        public void setLng(double lng) {
            this.lng = lng;
        }

        public double getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(double lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }
    }

    public static class Northeast {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("lng")
        private double lng;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("lat")
        private double lat;

        public double getLng() {
            return lng;
        }

        public void setLng(double lng) {
            this.lng = lng;
        }

        public double getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(double lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }
    }

    public static class Location {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("lng")
        private double lng;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("lat")
        private double lat;

        public double getLng() {
            return lng;
        }

        public void setLng(double lng) {
            this.lng = lng;
        }

        public double getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(double lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because your permission is getting denied from google apis. You need to enable the api before you start using it.

Comment: `Am I using retrofit the right way?` not really, you should be creating your API only once, and re-use it later.

Comment: Could you correct me in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Provided that you actually have an API Key already,** if not,

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key

Once you get your api key and you want to enable api and services, you can always go to your api console and enable apis and services,

Go to **https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?YOUR_PROJECT**

Click in the Enable Apis Button

[image: Enable APIS and Services]

Enable the APIs and services that you want to use.

You should enable **Maps SDK for Android** and any other services you might want to use.

**UPDATE:**

If you are making an Http request (e.g. @GET), please make sure that you don't place a restriction on your API in the api console.  So you need to go to your generated key and find the following and set to no restrictions,

[image: Google API Console]

**What will happen if you select Android only?**
You'll be able to use any objects and methods in the selected SDK (e.g. places/maps).

**For example, PlacePicker object in places API**.

I am giving reference to places sdk from developers website,

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro

But if you want make HTTP request then it will get denied as you have restrictions placed in your key.

Comment: I have enabled places sdk since nearby places come under it

Comment: API
Requests
Errors
Avg latency (ms)
Places SDK for Android 0 0 - Details
Places API for Web 9 8 - Details
Maps SDK for Android 83 0 - Details
Maps JavaScript API 0 0 - Details

Comment: The above are the enabled apis.Anything else i am missing

Comment: Go to your sdk and check if you have any application restrictions or not. Since you are making a get call, it means that you are actually making an http request. So you need to remove restrictions from the api (if any)

Comment: I have only restricted it to android apps

Comment: Remove the restriction and it will start working immediately. As I said, you are making an http request to get all the data. You are not using places library to fetch all the information. So that counts as a web request.

Comment: Could you tell me why it is so?Why wouldn't it work when I restricted to android apps?I havent tried it yet

Comment: I don't know how to take this session to chat instead to answer you some of the questions, I prefer not having long conversation in comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176346/discussion-between-jobin-and-mrah).